# How to create a comprehensible bar chart with matplotlib for more than 100 values?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, charts

I have a csv file with aproximatey 125 lines and two columns - username and number of tables. I am trying to create horizontal bar chart from this data using matplotlib. My goal is to export the bar chart in a pdf file. The problem is that I can not scale my chart inside the pdf file so that it is actually comprehensible.

This is my code so far (where values is the array with the number of tables/user and labels is an array with the corresponding usernames):

```
positions = np.arange(len(values)) + 0.5
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.barh(positions, values, align='center', color=colors)
plt.yticks(positions, labels)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
plt.xlabel('Nombre tables')
plt.title('Utilisateur')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('foo.pdf', papertype='a2')
```

And here is the result I get with the above code:

[image: Result from matplotlib]

I intentionally created the chart horizontally, so that it could be split on multiple pages in my pdf, but I can't seem to make it work. The entire image is rendered in one single page, and therefore becomes unreadable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

A copy-pastable example:

```
values=np.random.randint(0,100,(125,))
labels=[str(x) for x in values]
positions = np.arange(len(values)) + 0.5
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.barh(positions, values, align='center')
plt.yticks(positions, labels)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
plt.xlabel('Nombre tables')
plt.title('Utilisateur')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('foo.pdf', papertype='a2')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want several bar charts, each containing some of the data, like perhaps the first 20 bars on one plot and so on?

Comment: Try this `plt.figure(figsize=(23.39, 16.53)` and check

Comment: What TheBigH says :-) Readability/functionality might also be improved by sorting the bars.

Comment: TheBigH, I was actually trying to the entire bar chart into one A4 page (which I thought should have been enough to be readable ). However, I start to realise that other mesures would be more representative (such as a Gaussian distribution, a min, max, avg maybe).
Kirubaharan, that actually created a non-overlapping picture in my pdf file (which now must be zoomed to 200% for a nice reading) so this is great. Could you tell me how did you come up with those values?
Jan Kuiken - Sorting the bars and then showing only first/last k entries is also a good idea.
Thank you all for your answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The example below uses the idea of Kirubaharan J to set a bigget value to figsize. There is only vertical grid. The horizontal grid seems to have not any advantage.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = np.random.randint(0, 100, (125, ))
labels = [str(x) for x in values]
positions = np.arange(len(values)) + 0.5
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(24, 17))
plt.barh(positions, values, align='center')
plt.yticks(positions, labels)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=8)
plt.xlabel('Nombre tables')
plt.title('Utilisateur')
ax = plt.axes()
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
plt.savefig('foo.pdf', papertype='a2')
```